# Which server push technology is frequently used to refresh chess board on two player browser in online chess game?

Tags: javascript, java, web-applications, client-server

I am new to web development and like to create online chess game in which several player can login on system in internet and each player can challenge any other free player. When challenge is accepted then new game will be configured between the two players and server will captured the moves of both player and continuously push the most updated chess board to both player. Can you please guide me how to establish connection between both player and which server push technology will be good to update the chess board continuously?

Comment: Web sockets seems like a viable approach for this.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websockets might be an option for you. It will require to use some of the lates browsers.

You might want to take a look on https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere